# How to invoke .toDateString() on Date object in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, om, reagent

I'm trying to get the DateString in Clojurescript: `new Date(1420971497471).toDateString();`

I am having trouble because `(js/Date 1420971497471)` returns a string, so I can't call `.toDateString()`.

Here's my Clojurescript code:

```
(.toDateString (js/Date 1420971497471)) 
// Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(.toDateString (js/Date. 1420971497471))
```

Comment: (Foo. bar) is shorthand for (new Foo bar) in both clojure and clojurescript: http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-(Classname.%20args%2a)